# Why only n failed servers are allowed in multi-node Zookeper ensembles?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am reading through the theory for Apache Kafka and came across Zookeeper quorum allowance. I wanted to know why only `n` failed servers are allowed to keep a quorum? If we are using 5 servers, then why not allow 3 servers to fail and still not let Zookeeper go down? We are left with 2 servers here, which is the same if we use 3 server configuration and allow one to fail? Another question, if we allow 1 to fail in 3 server configuration, then isn't the odd number rule voilated? Or this odd number rule is for general case and we randomly select an output from the two in case of a clash?

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper won't "go down" with an even number. It'll just be confused because quorum, majority rule of (N+1) / 2 servers, cannot be reached amongst the remaining servers. e.g. With 3 brokers, 2 *in agreement* (not two in total, giving different information to each other) are needed for a quorum, or with 5, then 3 are needed